# can´t add fixtures to classpath

Tags: fitnesse

I´m porting FitNesse´s Slim-server to Qt and I´ve encountered a little problem.
I can´t seem to tell my new Slim-Server where to get the required fixtures.

Now there´s the possibility to add a path using

```
!path C:\path\
```

but this doesn´t seem to work for Slim. It doesn´t add anything to the command-line and it doesn´t send an import-instruction to my Slim-server. I do get every other instruction though, so my server isn´t the problem.
So now I need another way to either modify the command-line calling Slim or sending an import-instruction... any ideas?

EDIT: I tried import tables and got it working now. I´m still interested why the !path-thing didn´t work though.

Answer (score 0):

Put %p in your COMMAND_PATTERN and the path definitions will be placed there in the command line that executes your server.